# How to handle users joining a game room

Tags: php, ajax, multiplayer

I know this question is not coding specific and might be broad, but I just want to know the thinking process because I am a bit lost.

I am trying to make a simple board game with Ajax and PHP. I know making games with web sockets would be far better for real time experiences but for now I am keeping to Ajax and PHP only. Till now I have been able to create rooms for users but cant understand how to make other users join that room and account for their details like name, score etc.

**My situation:**

- I have an index page where users visit, and then the user fills in his name and chooses board size, then he is redirected to another page with a link like `playground.php?room=123456`
- Another user uses that link and enters that room but then I don't know how to identify that second player and store his details like his name etc to the db.

Comment: You can use sessions?

Comment: How to use sessions in this case?

Comment: If registered, (session or cookie exist, like a normal login system) they can play the game.. If not registered, show a registration page (maybe you can do this with bootstrap modals / jquery)..

Comment: Alright, can you take a look at snowfight.io and tell me how they manage the rooms and player additions to that room

Answer (score 1):

I should store data in a database and cookies.

In the **database**, you have **3 tables**

```
tblUsers (username, userid, ip,...)
tblRooms (roomid, creatorid,..)
tblPlayers (roomid,userid,..)
```

If a user visit your webpage, check for a cookie that has the userinfo.
If there is no cookie let the user login or register.

If a user creates a room, store this data in tblRooms.
Now he can share the link.

Another player visits the room. First you have to check if the player is registered (check for cookie). If not, let him show a registrationform.

If registered, store the user id in tblPlayers. With that table you know the players for that room.

Comment: I dont want to have any registration form. It should be like, fill your name, select board and get going. Then the user goes to playground page with the room number. Gives the link to his friend, he visits that page and then ?

Comment: Thats a registration form. You want to know his name,...  It's just with less information than normal..

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in PHP of course, but I would do this:

1) When a user fills in details in index page, you can save some basic info in local storage or using cookies, so you can get those details later.

If you have a database, then you can have a table in which you will save users...

2)When that user enters playground.php?room=123456 you can get those details you saved in localstorage or cookies and add that user to the database.

3) You check the database for the player who created the room every x amount of time and if there is a user you encounter for the first time, then you can do some action..

I hope this helps you a bit :)

Good luck with you project ;)

Comment: As long as I know, IPs cannot save data like cookies or localstorage can.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Am not asking about saving data in IPs which cant be done obviously. Instead I was thinking of saving the ip of the user who created the room and for other users verify that ip, if match not found then a modal pops up and asks users for their name and then save his details in db.

Comment: Ip's can be fake.. Or in 1 place, always be the same for multiple users..

Comment: Might be, I like that idea

Comment: @Finduilas what do you think about setting multiple cookies for different rooms? Then I wouldnt have to make repeated queries to db if a person refreshes the page again and again.